# Which design pattern is to use in below scenario?

Tags: design-patterns

I got this question in my interview- "There are two data source. First one is database system and another one is File System.Client code will only provide id whose data it needs to see and nothing else. The client logic doesn't need to know from where its getting the data for a particular id.Which design pattern should be used in this case?"

My best guess is Abstract Factory design pattern. I will use abstract class which will be inherited by database access class and file access class but I am unable to decipher how Client code will get the object of either database class or fileclass to access the file if we do not provide any other input?

Comment: with details at hand and assuming there is no collision between the ids from database and ids from the file system, a solution would be to run every data source available with given id and when one of the data source returns a non empty result stop running the remaining ones and return the result

Comment: Lets assume there is no collision of data and we might have to traverse both the database and file system. But my main concern is how client class should call these ? I am looking for design pattern to be implemented in this case.

Comment: [Strategy design pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-strategy-pattern) could be a solution. Have a strategy with 2 implementations (one for data base and one for file system) and a service method which is called with the id. When the service is called iterate over the list of the strategies and call each one with the given id, when one of the strategies returns a non empty result stop iterating and return the result